# How to return a list of custom mode from a custom query created using @query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I've a JPA DATA repository which contains a certain custom method, something like:

```
@Query(value=<quite-complex-query>, nativeQuery=true)
List<Object> myCustomRepoMethod();
```

Now the problem is that I'm returning a `List<Object>`, instead I want to return a list of `MyCustomType`, but it's not working, because the query is returning a few columns which apparently are not able to be mapped to `MyCustomType`'s fields.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA map the result to Non-Entity POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-result-to-non-entity-pojo)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying with `@Query(value=<quite-complex-query>, nativeQuery=true) List<MyCustomType> myCustomRepoMethod();`

Comment: Of course, I tried also with that, but it gives me an error of conversion from `[Object[]]` to `[MyCustomType]`.

Comment: check out this doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: i am looking for the reason of the issue

Comment: maybe the problem is in the query.. can you put it??

Comment: It's not in the query, which returns successfully what I'm querying. The problem is that the query is not aware of `MyCustomType`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) and [ConstructorResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) to achieve what you need.

This is an example of how to map your SQL result set to your POJO:

```
   Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS avgOrder " +
      "FROM Customer c, Orders o " +
      "WHERE o.cid = c.id " +
      "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
      "CustomerDetailsResult");

   @SqlResultSetMapping(
       name="CustomerDetailsResult",
       classes={
          @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
                 columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)
                    }
          )
       }
      )
```

Comment: Could you please give an example in the context of Spring JPA repositories, which are interfaces..

Comment: Put the  `@SqlResultSetMapping` bit in your Entity class. Put the SQL as the value of the `@Query annotation`.

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, but in the query above we have as second parameter `CustomerDetailsResult`...

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-result-to-non-entity-pojo Make it a Named Query and reference that from your Repository.

Comment: @AlanHay Apparently I should specify the `@NamedNativeQuery` above the class of the entity I want to return, right? I did it and I also created a dedicated repository for the entity I want to return from my initial query, where I put the method which returns my entity. Now I'm having the problem: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repoVariableAutowired'`.