# How to mapping subquery in select with jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring ,jpa, hibernate,mysql , java 8,.In Dao (which is inteface and extends JpaRepository)
**MyTable class**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
    private String itemName;
    @Column(name = "ITEM_PRICE")
    private int itemPrice;
    @Transient
    private int col1;

    public MyTable() {
    }
    public MyTable(long id, String itemName, int itemPrice, int col1) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.col1 = col1;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public int getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }
    public void setItemPrice(int itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
    public int getCol1() {
        return col1;
    }
    public void setCol1(int col1) {
        this.col1 = col1;
    }


}
```

**MyTableDao**

```
  import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.kolip.devchain.model.MyTable;

public interface MyTableDao extends JpaRepository<MyTable   , Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT mt.*, (select count(1) from anotherTable ) as col1 from MY_TABLE mt",nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyTable> getMyTableList();
}
```

pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

</dependency>

        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
  <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**MY_TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
   `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `ITEM_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ITEM_PRICE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I try to simplify my problem.I try to get col1 value but i can't find out how should be col1 attribute in entity. Other values can be gotten in entity.

If i use col1 attribute without @Transient , it will work , but col1 is not persistant(Also findAll() not working because there isn't col1 column on db). What should i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA map the result to Non-Entity POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-result-to-non-entity-pojo)

Comment: Did'nt get you..you should provide more details about values in table so we can design the entity class for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have many options but you could try this the following steps if you are using JPA 2.1:

1) Create a suitable DTO which should include properties that will take the results of your query:
"SELECT mt.*, (select count(1) from anotherTable ) as col1 from MY_TABLE mt"

2) In the MyTable entity, map the native query to your DTO using the @SqlResultSetMapping and @ConstructorResult annotations (a simple search on google will give you lots of usefull info on its usage).(See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

3) Modify the MyTableDao to use the native query you created in step 2.

I hope this helps. Goodluck :)

Comment: i did like this but i map native query to same entity and use namednativequery to use in jparepository. But this doesn't look clean because query is in entity class , i try to store all of them in dao. Also i wonder that can i map only transient attribute and others are mapped default ?