# Object mapping in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a **native query** inside a **JPA repository** :

```
public interface TaskRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Task, Integer> {
    @Query( nativeQuery = true, value = "select min(t_id) as id, sum(t_estimation_time) as estimationTime, max(t_due_date) as maxDueDate, min(t_due_date) as minDueDate  "
                + "from kat_task inner join kat_task_to_workstream on t_id = ttw_frn_task_id "
                + "inner join kat_workstream on ws_id = ttw_frn_workstream_id and t_is_active is true and t_completed_at is null and t_is_active is true "
                + "where ws_id= :workstreamId" )
        DueDatesAndEstimationTimeBean getDueDatesAndEstimationTime( @Param( "workstreamId" ) Integer workstreamId );

    }
```

But, when I run the above query I am getting exception

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
>   [com.kat.beans.DueDatesAndEstimationTimeBean] for value '{15666,
>   10800000, 2017-04-27 14:21:16.0, 2017-03-13 12:20:33.0}'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to
>   type [com.kat.beans.DueDatesAndEstimationTimeBean].

Why it is failing to convert? I am new to spring data JPA. Please help

Comment: format your code. this way it is impossible to read

Comment: What does the DueDatesAndEstimationTimeBean look like and how does it relate to Task? Edit: oh wait, you got the generics wrong, too. It's entity and id, right?

Comment: @rob Ya they are the entity and Id. But can't I map to other POJO than the entity?

Comment: Are you required to write a native query? with JPQL you can use `SELECT new DueDateAndEstimationTimeBean( MIN(t.id) AS id, SUM(t.estimationTime), <the rest of your select>) FROM KatTast t <the rest of your query>.`

Comment: here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-result-to-non-entity-pojo