# JPA Returning Table name in case of join of unrelated tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have Tables A & B and I join them. I am using JPA with Spring rest. Problem is what table name I am supposed to use to load my search results into.

In normal case if I return results for table A, I can do 
`public List<A> fun1(){...}`    
 or
`public List<B> fun2(){...}` 
But what do I return as Object type in list if I run a custom join query between unrelated tables?

```
public List<what?> nativeQueryJoinfun(){....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 options:

- Object[]
- use a projection to DTO

For the second case, see for example:
[Spring Data JPA map the native query result to Non-Entity POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-native-query-result-to-non-entity-pojo)