# Jpa select query to a new object gives error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When assign select JPA It gives an error as bellow. What is the issue?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.finance.resources.StudentForBankStatement(s.admission_no,s.first' at line 1`

Query

```
@Query( value = "select NEW com.finance.resources.StudentForBankStatement(s.admission_no,s.first_name,s.last_name) from student s where branch_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true )
List<StudentForBankStatement> getStudentByClassIdBranchId( long branchId );
```

Helper Class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentForBankStatement
{
    private String AdmissionNo;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA map the native query result to Non-Entity POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-native-query-result-to-non-entity-pojo)

Comment: I tried these solutions @Stuck but the error remain same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have `nativeQuery=true` which this is not, thus the error. This should be JPQL. Fix your query to something like:

```
@Query( value = "select NEW com.finance.resources.StudentForBankStatement(s.admissionNo, s.firstName, s.lastName) from Student s where s.branchId = :1")
```