# The column name is not valid. -> Could not JPA just replace it will null in this case?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, mssql-jdbc

I have searched all over stackoverflow.com but I have not found this discussion.

I know my problem, I was just wondering if JPA can handle this in any way without a lot of work...

What I have is an @Entity that I want to use with multiple SQL-Native-Queries.

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private String ID;
    private String ID1;
    private String ID2;
    private String ID3;
}
```

Names in the database are equal to Field names.

I then have two selects:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 from DATABASE;
SELECT ID2 from DATABASE;
```

And two native queries for those selects:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT ID2 from DATABASE", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TestEntity> testNativeQuery ();
```

And the Error I get:

```
[ERROR] 2021-11-30 10:37:20 [main] [SqlExceptionHelper] The column name ID1 is not valid.
```

How could I tell JPA that if it does not find the Column name that it should just replace it will

> null
> ?

Would that be so difficult?

---

Some extra details:

I am using a Stored Procedure - which means I can not change the Query - The Stored Procedures are maintained by someone else.

Stored procedure (which works):

```
    @Query(value = "STORED_PROC :a, :b", nativeQuery = true)
    List<List<String>> execStoredProc(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
```

Stored procedure that does not work, because I have more fields in the entity that the Procedure return, because I need those fields in other stored procedures:

```
@Query(value = "STORED_PROC :a, :b", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TestEntity> execStoredProc(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
```

When I remove those field the function works - but I need those fields in other part of my program - and I hoped I could use the same @Entity

Database I am using is MSSQL Database:

`driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Comment: Your entity contains ID, ID1, ID2, ID3 so all these columsn have to exist in the database table

Comment: They do - that is not the problem here - The problem is that the `SELECT` statement does  not return all the IDs - If I do a: 

`SELECT ID, ID1, ID2, ID3 FROM DATABASE` 

then it works... 

I would like to have all the other values - that are not in SELECT - that they would be automaticaly "null" since they are declared as Strings

Comment: Why return TestEntity entity instances from the query? You should try returning a non-entity class if you want it partially populated/incomplete, otherwise it will cause inconsistencies with the persistence unit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966870/496099

Comment: That is my current solution - I am returning `List<List<String>>` I find it rather annoying though - since I have a well organised @Entity and someone has just omitted one Field from a Stored Procedure I want to use - I do not know why does it need to Fail and Throw an Exception instead of just filling that Field with a Null value? Or maybe i could define the @Entity if the Column is not found then it is "null" or "columnNotFound" or sth? 

Why would that not be possible? What kind of inconsistencies could arise in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the missing columns as null:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS ID1, ID2, NULL AS ID3 from DATABASE", nativeQuery = true)
List<TestEntity> testNativeQuery ();
```

Comment: that would work... however the query in my case is actually a Stored Procedure and I am not allowed to change it - Is there a way where JPA would be so smart to automatically create a Null value if it does not find it? :)

Comment: No this is not possible. How do you call the stored procedure and which database are you using?

Comment: Stored procedure (which works): 
`@Query(value = "STORED_PROC :a, :b", nativeQuery = true)
 List<List<String>> execStoredProc(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);`
Stored procedure that does not work, because I have more fields in the entity that the Procedure return, because I need those fields in other stored procedures:

`@Query(value = "STORED_PROC :a, :b", nativeQuery = true)
 List<TestEntity> execStoredProc(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);`

Database I am using is MSSQL Database:

`driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Comment: I will add an answer I guess :) this is really dificult to format in a comment :)

Comment: Or better yet I have edited the Question :) I would also be nice if someone Upvoted the question so it could get more traction.. It is a valid question, or is it not? :)

I tried to upvote your answer since it would work if I did not have that constraind of not changing the query.. but I can t because my rating is not high enough yet :(