# spring data jpa map result set to non-entity pojo and convert to jackson

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

We are using spring data jpa and we have a native query in one of the repo. The result of this query we want to map to non-entity pojo. Everything works fine but the returned result is a list of objects instead of non-entity pojo class.

Once this list of pojo is fetched we want to be converted to json response. Which is working fine for other api but not when we are using non-entity classes.

Does anyone had done something like this?

Comment: spring data jpa will not directly map result of native query to non-entity pojo you have code for that...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420697/spring-data-jpa-how-can-query-return-non-entities-objects-or-list-of-objects

Comment: What if you use mybatis, to return the result to a pojo class.