# JPA Data Repositories with SqlResultSetMapping and native queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, nativequery, sqlresultsetmapping

I was stuck with the following situation:

My entities are related to each other, but in such a way that i could not use JPQL. I was forced to use native SQL. Now I want to map these results to a ValueObject. To be clear, I don't want to get a list of Object array (`List<Object[]>`). I have 6 entities from which I need only some columns. Can anybody give me an example on how to implement such a mapping from a native query?

[Tutorial](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/) that I went through.

My code:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "findAllDataMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = MyVO.class,
            columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "userFirstName"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "userLastName"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "packageName")
            }
    )
)

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDataMapping",
    query = "SELECT " +
            "    u.first_name as userFirstName, " +
            "    u.last_name as userLastName, " +
            "    i.id as id, " +
            "    s.title as packageName, " +
            "FROM " +
            "    invoice as i " +
            "JOIN user as u on i.user_id=u.id " +
            "LEFT JOIN subscription_package as s on i.subscription_package_id=s.id " +
            "where  u.param1=:param1 and i.param2=:param2" +
)

public class MyVO {
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private Long id;
    private String packageName;

    public MyVO (String userFName, String userLName,
            Long id, String packageName) {
        this.userFirstName = userFName;
        this.userLastName = userLName;
        this.id = id;
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

In my jpa-repository module:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    List<MyVO> findAllOfMyVO(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2);
}
```

The point is that I don't know where to put these annotations so I can use this kind of mapping. In a native query I can't use `new rs.rado.leo.mypackage.MyVO(...)`. I got following error:

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllOfMyVO found for type MyEntity!
```

I suppose that my question is clear. If not, let me know so I can edit my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The anser is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42942353/355438

Comment: Some of the annotations seems to be outdated. 
I looked at this page to make them work.
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/java-jpa/src/main/java/com/baeldung/jpa/sqlresultsetmapping/Employee.java

Answer (score 26):

Add the missing resultClass

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDataMapping", resultClass = Entity.class, query="sql")
```

Or

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDataMapping", resultClass = MyVO.class, resultSetMapping ="findAllDataMapping" query = "sql")
```

and lastly call the query in your repository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, name = "findAllDataMapping")
List<MyVO> findAllOfMyVO(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are almost there, but for the below parts

1. The whole `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@NamedNativeQuery` has to be
   present in the Entity and not the value Object. In your case it should be in the MyEntity class and **not ** the MyVO class. This should resolve your exception.
2. That will still not do. After you do the above, change the below

   @NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDataMapping",
   to
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "**MyEntity**.findAllDataMapping",
3. Finally, in some cases you need to be explicit in your definition of @ColumnResult(name = "userFirstName"). If it is a complex field like ZonedDateTime or Boolean you may have to explicity state @ColumnResult(name = "date_created", type = ZonedDateTime.class).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This did not work for me
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyEntity.findAllDataMapping",  
Instead I did as Michelan Arendse suggested
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDataMapping", resultClass = MyVO.class, resultSetMapping ="findAllDataMapping" query = "sql")

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your query as a query :)
And you need to use **MyVO** instead of **MyEntity**, because that is the entity you have your resulsts mapped to

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyVO, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyVO> findAllOfMyVO(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @Urosh T. I know your answer is from 2012. I'm trying to do something like that but when the repository is initialize I obtain the error "Not a managed type" even if I declare no method in it. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: @elamas, it is from September 12th this year :)
`"Not a managed type"` probably means that Spring hasn't scanned your @Entity class or the package containing the class.
Make sure you have in your `application.properties` line that says `entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.mypack.entity`

Comment: Hi @Urosh T,
You're right, "September 12th this year :)". I think that the problem is that MyVO class is not an entity. But don't worry, I have found another aproaches, thanks.

Comment: How did you solve the `Not a managed type` problem, @elamas? In my case, MyVO is indeed **not** an Entity, but I want to map the results of my query to MyVO nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

your `@NamedNativeQuery` are missing properties `resultClass` and `resultSetMapping` like below sample:

```java
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "YourEntity.findAllDataMapping",
    resultClass =  MyVO.class ,
    resultSetMapping ="findAllDataMapping",
    query = "SELECT ..."
)
```