# Can I map the result of a hibernate/jpa query to a class that is not an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am experimenting with Springboot, I have several entities with several properties that are very similar, example: The entity "Car" has model and price properties so do the "Motorcycle" model. I would like to use a a class to define just those common attributes,  class "Vehicle" with the properties model and price.

In another words:

```
Car                             Motorcicle                             Vehicle
price                              price                                price
model                              model                                 model
year                              year
color                              color
fuel_type                         fuel_type
... 30 more properites                ...30 more properties
```

I want to use vehicle to map the search result of a SQL union between Car and Motorcycle tables.

```
public interface ImovelRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {

      @Query(value = "here select query with union between car and motorcycle", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Vehicle> searchVehicle();

}
```

Here Vehicle class is a normal class without any annotation. I am getting errors saying that Vehicle is not managed type. Of course my repository doesn't make sense, I expected this error. But how can I achieve what I want?

When I perform a union I am not getting a list of models  and am getting a list of one or more models. I want to create a class to "combine" the result of a search.

Comment: you may try the following query, but i'm not sure that is it works `SELECT new Vehicle(price, model)
  FROM car
 UNION
SELECT price, model
  FROM motorycycle`

Comment: I am not concerned about the sql query. I am brand new to Springboot but I think the error is because repository expects an entity and I am using a normal class. Besides used the Car, motorcycle and Vehicle to summarize my problem and make it easier to understand. My problem is a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @MappedSuperClass where the Vehicle can be the mapped super class. The remaining classes can just extend it. Somewhat like below:

The super class:

```
@MappedSuperClass
class Vehicle {
// constructor, getters, setters 
}
```

The entity classes:

```
@Entity
class Car extends Vehicle {
// constructor, getters, setters 
}

@Entity
class MotorCicle extends Vehicle {
// constructor, getters, setters 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FluentJPA has a [solution](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Entities-&-Tuples) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use SpringData JPA. In JPQL you can implement this by writing `select new fully.qualified.name.of.your.Class(field1, field2) from Entity` etc. You have to have proper constructor in your class `fully.qualified.name.of.your.Class`. This class does NOT have to be an `@Entity` - it can be any usual POJO or anything else you want.

However, I see that you also use native query. For native query this will not work - you'll have to declare return type as `List<Object[]>` and do mapping from that yourself, or use `@NamedNativeQuery` with `@SqlResultSetMapping`. But do you really need a native query there?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171583/jpa-data-repositories-with-sqlresultsetmapping-and-native-queries