# Mapping a DTO class using @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a `SQL` in a `repository` class

```
@Repository
public interface OrdemServicoRepository extends RepositoryBase<OrdemServico, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
            "os.orse_id, " +
            "os.cbdo_id, " +
            "os.orse_cdsituacao, " +
            "os.orse_tmgeracao, " +
            "os.orse_vlservicooriginal, " +
            "os.imov_id, " +
            "os.svtp_id, " +
            "ra.rgat_id, " +
            "st.svtp_dsservicotipo, " +
            "fg.ftgr_dsfaturamentogrupo, " +
            "c.clie_id, " +
            "c.clie_nmcliente, " +
            "cep.cep_dslogradourotipo, " +
            "lg.logr_nmlogradouro, " +
            "i.imov_nnimovel, " +
            "cep.cep_cdcep, " +
            "b.bair_nmbairro, " +
            "cep.cep_nmmunicipio, " +
            "h.hidr_nnhidrometro, " +
            "hp.hipr_dshidrometroprotecao, " +
            "hli.hili_dshidrometrolocalinstalacao, " +
            "lg.logr_id " +
            "FROM atendimentopublico.ordem_servico os " +
            "LEFT JOIN atendimentopublico.servico_tipo st ON st.svtp_id = os.svtp_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN atendimentopublico.registro_atendimento ra ON ra.rgat_id = os.rgat_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.imovel i ON os.imov_id = i.imov_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.rota r ON i.rota_id = r.rota_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN faturamento.faturamento_grupo fg ON fg.ftgr_id = r.ftgr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(clie_id) AS clie_id, imov_id FROM cadastro.cliente_imovel WHERE clim_icnomeconta = 1 AND clim_dtrelacaofim IS NULL GROUP BY imov_id) ci ON ci.imov_id = i.imov_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.cliente c ON c.clie_id = ci.clie_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.logradouro_bairro lb ON lb.lgbr_id = i.lgbr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.bairro b ON b.bair_id = lb.bair_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.logradouro lg ON lg.logr_id = lb.logr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT logr_id, MAX(cep_id) cep_id FROM cadastro.logradouro_cep GROUP BY logr_id) lgc ON lgc.logr_id = lg.logr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN cadastro.cep cep ON cep.cep_id = lgc.cep_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.hidrometro_instalacao_historico hih ON hih.lagu_id = i.imov_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.hidrometro h ON h.hidr_id = hih.hidr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.hidrometro_protecao AS hp ON hp.hipr_id = hih.hipr_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.hidrometro_local_instalacao hli ON hli.hili_id = hih.hili_id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "os.orse_cdsituacao = 1 " +
            "AND hih.hidi_dtretiradahidrometro IS NULL " +
            "AND os.svtp_id IN (:servicosTipo) " +
            "ORDER BY " +
            "os.orse_id",

            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
                    "FROM atendimentopublico.ordem_servico os " +
                    "LEFT JOIN atendimentopublico.servico_tipo st ON st.svtp_id = os.svtp_id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(clie_id) AS clie_id, imov_id FROM cadastro.cliente_imovel " +
                    "WHERE 1 = 1 " +
                    "AND clim_icnomeconta = 1 " +
                    "AND clim_dtrelacaofim IS NULL " +
                    "GROUP BY imov_id) ci ON ci.imov_id = os.imov_id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN micromedicao.hidrometro_instalacao_historico hih ON hih.lagu_id = ci.imov_id " +
                    "WHERE os.orse_cdsituacao = 1 " +
                    "AND hih.hidi_dtretiradahidrometro IS NULL " +
                    "AND st.svtp_id IN (:servicosTipo)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<OrdemServicoDTO> getOrdensServicoPaginadas(@Param("servicosTipo") List<Integer> servicosTipo, Pageable pageable);
```

And DTO class

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "getOrdensServicoPaginadas", entities = {
    @EntityResult(entityClass = br.com.gsan_mobile.dto.OrdemServicoDTO.class,
        fields = {
            @FieldResult(name = "idOS", column = "os.orse_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "situacaoOS", column = "os.orse_cdsituacao"),
            @FieldResult(name = "valorServico", column = "os.orse_vlservicooriginal"),
            @FieldResult(name = "idServicoTipo", column = "os.svtp_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "idDocumentoCobranca", column = "os.cbdo_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "descricaoServicoTipo", column = "st.svtp_dsservicotipo"),
            @FieldResult(name = "grupo", column = "fg.ftgr_dsfaturamentogrupo"),
            @FieldResult(name = "matriculaImovel", column = "i.imov_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "matriculaCliente", column = "c.clie_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "nomeCliente", column = "c.clie_nmcliente"),
            @FieldResult(name = "tipoLogradouro", column = "cep.cep_dslogradourotipo"),
            @FieldResult(name = "logradouro", column = "lg.logr_nmlogradouro"),
            @FieldResult(name = "numeroImovel", column = "i.imov_nnimovel"),
            @FieldResult(name = "numeroCep", column = "cep.cep_cdcep"),
            @FieldResult(name = "bairro", column = "b.bair_nmbairro"),
            @FieldResult(name = "municipio", column = "cep.cep_nmmunicipio"),
            @FieldResult(name = "numeroHidrometro", column = "h.hidr_nnhidrometro"),
            @FieldResult(name = "protecaoHidrometro", column = "hp.hipr_dshidrometroprotecao"),
            @FieldResult(name = "localInstalacaoHidrometro", column = "hli.hili_dshidrometrolocalinstalacao"),
            @FieldResult(name = "idRegistroAtendimento", column = "ra.rgat_id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "dataGeracao", column = "os.orse_tmgeracao"),
            @FieldResult(name = "imovel", column = "os.imov_id")
        })
})
@Data
public class OrdemServicoDTO {

    private Integer idOS;

    private Short situacaoOS;

    private BigDecimal valorServico;

    private Integer idServicoTipo;

    private Integer idDocumentoCobranca;

    private String descricaoServicoTipo;

    private String grupo;

    private Integer matriculaImovel;

    private Integer matriculaCliente;

    private String nomeCliente;

    private String tipoLogradouro;

    private String logradouro;

    private String numeroImovel;

    private Integer numeroCep;

    private String bairro;

    private String municipio;

    private String numeroHidrometro;

    private String protecaoHidrometro;

    private String localInstalacaoHidrometro;

    private Integer idRegistroAtendimento;

    private Integer quantPaginas;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date dataGeracao;

    private Integer imovel;

    private List<ContaEmAbertoDTO> contasEmAberto;

    private Integer idLocalInstalacaoNova;

    private Integer idProtecaoHidrometroNova;

    private Integer idMotivoEncerramento;

    private String leitura;

    private String lacre;

    private String descricaoParecerEncerramento;

    private Integer usuarioEncerrouOS;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date dataExecucaoDate;

}
```

And when I call sql method gave me exception

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [br.com.gsan_mobile.dto.OrdemServicoDTO]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:213) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:899) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk.getConvertedContent(Chunk.java:167) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:30) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:141) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.getOrdensServicoPaginadas(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.gsan_mobile.service.OrdemServicoService.getPaginado(OrdemServicoService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.gsan_mobile.resource.ResourceBase.getPaginado(ResourceBase.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

I followed tutorials, but didn´t worked to me, and don´t wanna transform my DTO to interface class, because one field needs to be populate after.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception provides a big hint on how to solve this problem:

- the `@Query` in `OrdemServicoRepository` returns a list of tuples
- the expected result is a list of `OrdemServicoDTO`

To solve this problem I would use a JPQL Constructor Expression (with a JPQL Query):

```
@Query(value="SELECT new br.com.gsan_mobile.dto.OrdemServicoDTO(os.orse_id,...
```

With a native SQL Query, you would have to use a `@NamedNativeQuery` (instead of the `@Query`) with the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation (with the correct name mapping). I think you also need to move the `@NamedNativeQuery` to the method in the repository class.

```
@Repository
public interface OrdemServicoRepository extends RepositoryBase<OrdemServico, Integer> {

    @SqlResultSetMapping(name="resultSetMappingName",columns={...})
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "queryName", query = "...", resultSetMapping = "resultSetMappingName"
    Page<OrdemServicoDTO> getOrdensServicoPaginadas(@Param("servicosTipo") List<Integer> servicosTipo, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I tryed to put `@SqlResultSetMapping` in the method, but compiler tells me that I can´t do that

Comment: Indeed, the second part of my answer is obviously wrong. I will have a look tonight. In the mean time you can have look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171583/jpa-data-repositories-with-sqlresultsetmapping-and-native-queries