# Average of difference between two dates using Hibernate JPA in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, datediff

I'm having a table with columns: id, task_type, start_time, end_time. I need to get the Average Time taken by each task. In SQL query I could do:

`SELECT task_type, AVG(DATEDIFF(MS, end_time, start_time)) AS average_time GROUP BY task_type`

I'm unable to use the DATEDIFF in JPA as it's not supported. If I pass the nativeQury to the JPA `"@Query"` It shows the column names which are not included in SELECT statement as Invalid, suppose if I pass the aforementioned query as native query I get error `the column name id is not valid`.

It would be a great help if anyone is able to point out what I'm missing here.

**Note:** The project is a micro service architecture, database is stored in a Microsoft SQL Server and the API is being written in Spring Boot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by creating the Projection class and JPQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding calling vendor-specific and user-defined functions, see [this tutorial](https://thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/) on ways you can do that from JPQL.

The `function()` syntax might not work for you due to the `MS` parameter (you could *probably* register a Hibernate user type for that, which is a nuissance). Registering a function in the dialect should work just fine, though. You'll probably want to implement `SQLFunction` yourself, rather than using the `StandardSQLFunction` implementation.

As for why the native query doesn't work for you, what is the result class you're trying to map your query onto? Try using an interface or a DTO with the same property names as the aliases used in the query, similar to how you would use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). If that doesn't work, a [result set mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171583/jpa-data-repositories-with-sqlresultsetmapping-and-native-queries) should.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd write that in JPQL:

```
 SELECT ent.taskType, AVG( EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM (ent.endTime - ent.startTime)))
 FROM Entity ent
 GROUP BY ent.taskType
```

This is the result in seconds, you can manipulate de extract result to whatever you want to show in view.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL:

```
select taskType, avg(day(endTime - startTime))
from entity
group by taskType
```