# Map result set to custom pojo which is not entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

I need to fetch 4 columns by joining multiple tables. I have created the query. But how can I map the result set to a pojo which is not an entity and i want to use Spring Data JPA.

Could someone please help?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
Custom POJO class:

`

```
@Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = CustomPojo.retriveCustomPojo
            query = Constants.CUSTOM_QUERY, resultSetMapping = CustomDataMapping")
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CustomDataMapping",
            classes = {
                    @ConstructorResult(
                            targetClass = CustomPojo.class,
                            columns = {
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "NAME"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "TYPE"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "TITLE"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "DESCRIPTION")
                            }
                            )
                }
        )
    public class CustomPojo implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String name
        private String type;
        private String title;
        private String description;

    }
```

`

Comment: show your entity class and query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956042/mapping-a-jdbc-resultset-to-an-object this might help

Comment: @Mad Man - I am using Spring Data JPA. I cannot use that.

Comment: @pvpkiran - I have added the Pojo class. NOTE: Its not entity. From the query I want to directly map the result which will have 4 columns to this Pojo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-native-query-result-to-non-entity-pojo what abt this?

Comment: Its not working. Whatever I am trying its not possible. Because for to use `@SqlResultSetMapping` class must be entity class. Can anyone confirm? If that's true, how can I achieve my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The annotations must be on an entity! It's not possible to have them on a POJO.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = CustomPojo.retriveCustomPojo
            query = Constants.CUSTOM_QUERY, resultSetMapping = CustomDataMapping")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CustomDataMapping",
            classes = {
                    @ConstructorResult(
                            targetClass = CustomPojo.class,
                            columns = {
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "NAME"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "TYPE"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "TITLE"),
                                    @ColumnResult(name = "DESCRIPTION")
                            }
                            )
                }
        )
```

Another way is to use QLRM to get rid of these annotations.

Have a look at the GitHub Page: https://github.com/simasch/qlrm

Comment: I got it solved. I applied the annotations on the entity. But now i am getting this error `Got different size of tuples and aliases`

Comment: How does  Constants.CUSTOM_QUERY look like?

Comment: Actually, this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056084/got-different-size-of-tuples-and-aliases-exception-after-spring-boot-2-0-0-rel/49985099#49985099 worked. second answer. But not sure that is permanent solution or not.

Comment: Here is my query
`select book.name, book.type, title.title, title.description from book book join details title on (title.id = book.id)`

Comment: And this is my interface method
`@Query(name = "CustomPojo.retriveCustomPojo", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CustomPojo> retriveCustomPojo();`

Comment: and the types of the columns name, type, title and description are all String?