# Spring Data 2.1.1 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Got different size of tuples and aliases?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading from `1.5.4` of Spring Boot to `2.1.0 LTS`

I am getting some issues with particular repository methods.

I checked the various issues on SO and JIRA mentioning `@Query` and `@ResultsSetMapping` and have applied those changes accordingly, however I still facing the same issue.

For example here:

**Repository**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/iCreateChange")
public interface ICreateChangeRepository extends JpaRepository<ICreateChange, Long> {

  List<ChangeTask> listStartedChangesByInitiator(
        @Param("initiator")
        @RequestParam
        @ApiParam(name = "initiator", value = "initiator")
        String initiator);

  List<ChangeTask> listDataValuesAndStatusByChangeId(
        @Param("changeId")
        @RequestParam
        @ApiParam(name = "changeId", value = "changeId")
        Long changeId);
}
```

**Entity**

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
      name = "StartedChangeMapping",
      classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = ChangeTask.class,
        columns = {
          @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
          @ColumnResult(name = "status", type = String.class),
          @ColumnResult(name = "data_values", type = String.class)
        }
      )
    ),
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
      name = "ActiveTaskChangeMapping",
      classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = ChangeTask.class,
        columns = {
          @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
          @ColumnResult(name = "status", type = String.class),
          @ColumnResult(name = "data_values", type = String.class)
        }
      )
    )
})
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "ICreateChange.listStartedChangesByInitiator",
      query =
      "SELECT id as id, status as status, data_values as data_values "
      + "FROM icreate_change "
      + "WHERE initiator = :initiator "
      + "AND workflow_process_id = 0",
      resultSetMapping = "StartedChangeMapping"
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "ICreateChange.listDataValuesAndStatusByChangeId",
      query =
      "SELECT id as id, status as status, data_values as data_values "
      + "FROM icreate_change "
      + "WHERE id = :changeId",
      resultSetMapping = "ActiveTaskChangeMapping"
    )

})

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "icreate_change")
public class ICreateChange {

  public ICreateChange() {}
....
```

Have I missed something?

**Stack Trace**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Got different size of tuples and aliases
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.NativeQueryTupleTransformer$NativeTupleImpl.<init>(NativeQueryTupleTransformer.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.NativeQueryTupleTransformer.transformTuple(NativeQueryTupleTransformer.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

**Debugging**

Debugging the implementation of `NativeTupleImpl` shows that the aliases and tuples are there, however there is a nesting problem. There is one tuple object with all values, but there are 3 aliases which are not nested and are as three entities. Which is causing the mismatch

[image]

Reference:

https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATAJPA-1280/DATAJPA-1280.html

["Got different size of tuples and aliases" exception after Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056084/got-different-size-of-tuples-and-aliases-exception-after-spring-boot-2-0-0-rel)

Comment: You missed adding the full stack trace.

Comment: Added @Selaron !

Comment: Did you debug into `org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135) ` to view which query causes this issue and `org.hibernate.jpa.spi.NativeQueryTupleTransformer$NativeTupleImpl.(NativeQueryTupleTransformer.java:68)` to see which tuples and aliases are given as arguments there?

Comment: Added a screenshot, it seems they are nested at different levels.

Comment: If you are sure that you found a new or not completely fixed bug, you might want to create a [mcve] and file a new issue.

Comment: I think I will just downgrade, this is clearly not stable version :(

Comment: @tomaytotomato that's not the right attitude. If it has been released, they consider it stable. So please fill an issue with a self contained test case. Otherwise your issue will never get fixed.

Comment: I will do it later, right now I need to make it work as its blocking development work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with how Hibernate maps its Tuple Entity by default into an Object or list of Objects.

In this case it was expecting three tuples to map to individual columns in the POJO.

This is the code to get it working (note the omission of `@ConstructorResult`)

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "TaskChangeMapping",
        columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "status", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "data_values", type = String.class)

})
```