# JPA query is throwing a 'not found' error for column that isn't in query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to call for only specific columns in my DB but the query is throwing an error saying that the next column is not found (even though it's not in the query)

Is there a problem in the join that's doin this? I'm a bit perplexed as to this problem.

JPA Query from ConnectionRequestRepository -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT connection_request.id, connection_request.userId, connection_request.dateTimeCompleted, connection_request.phoneNumber " +
        "FROM ***.connection_request " +
        "INNER JOIN ***.user " +
        "ON ***.connection_request.userID = ***.user.id " +
        "WHERE connection_request.dateTimeCompleted IS NULL " +
        "LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
ConnectionRequest findActiveRequest();
```

Service -

```
public ConnectionRequest getActiveRequestToCaller() {
   return connectionRequestRepository.findActiveRequest();
}
```

Controller -

```
ConnectionRequest currentLocationRequest = connectionRequestService.getActiveRequestToCaller();
```

ConnectionRequest Class -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "connection_request")
public class ConnectionRequest {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
@NotNull
private Long id;
@Column(name = "userId")
@NotNull
private Long userId;
@Column(name = "uuid")
@NotNull
private UUID uuid;
@Column(name = "phoneNumber")
@NotNull
private String phoneNumber;
@Column(name = "locationSource")
@NotNull
private String locationSource;
@Column(name = "dateTimeRequested")
private Timestamp dateTimeRequested;
@Column(name = "dateTimeRequestExpires")
private Timestamp dateTimeRequestExpires;
@Column(name = "dateTimeCompleted")
private Timestamp dateTimeCompleted;
@Column(name = "s3Bucket")
private String s3Bucket;
@Column(name = "s3Key")
private String  s3Key;
@Column(name = "s3Etag")
private String s3Etag;
@Column(name = "s3Sha256Hash")
private String s3Sha256Hash;
@Column(name = "isScheduledForCompletion")
@NotNull
private Integer isScheduledForCompletion;

public ConnectionRequest() {}

public ConnectionRequest(Long id,
                         Long userId,
                         UUID uuid,
                         String phoneNumber,
                         String locationSource,
                         Timestamp dateTimeRequested,
                         Timestamp dateTimeRequestExpires,
                         Timestamp dateTimeCompleted,
                         String s3Bucket,
                         String s3Key,
                         String s3Etag,
                         String s3Sha256Hash,
                         Integer isScheduledForCompletion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.locationSource = locationSource;
    this.dateTimeRequested = dateTimeRequested;
    this.dateTimeRequestExpires = dateTimeRequestExpires;
    this.dateTimeCompleted = dateTimeCompleted;
    this.s3Bucket = s3Bucket;
    this.s3Key = s3Key;
    this.s3Etag = s3Etag;
    this.s3Sha256Hash = s3Sha256Hash;
    this.isScheduledForCompletion = isScheduledForCompletion;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getLocationSource() {
    return locationSource;
}

public void setLocationSource(String locationSource) {
    this.locationSource = locationSource;
}

public Timestamp getDateTimeRequested() {
    return dateTimeRequested;
}

public void setDateTimeRequested(Timestamp dateTimeRequested) {
    this.dateTimeRequested = dateTimeRequested;
}

public Timestamp getDateTimeRequestExpires() {
    return dateTimeRequestExpires;
}

public void setDateTimeRequestExpires(Timestamp dateTimeRequestExpires) {
    this.dateTimeRequestExpires = dateTimeRequestExpires;
}

public Timestamp getDateTimeCompleted() {
    return dateTimeCompleted;
}

public void setDateTimeCompleted(Timestamp dateTimeCompleted) {
    this.dateTimeCompleted = dateTimeCompleted;
}

public String getS3Bucket() {
    return s3Bucket;
}

public void setS3Bucket(String s3Bucket) {
    this.s3Bucket = s3Bucket;
}

public String getS3Key() {
    return s3Key;
}

public void setS3Key(String s3Key) {
    this.s3Key = s3Key;
}

public String getS3Etag() {
    return s3Etag;
}

public void setS3Etag(String s3Etag) {
    this.s3Etag = s3Etag;
}

public String getS3Sha256Hash() {
    return s3Sha256Hash;
}

public void setS3Sha256Hash(String s3Sha256Hash) {
    this.s3Sha256Hash = s3Sha256Hash;
}

public Integer getIsScheduledForCompletion() {
    return isScheduledForCompletion;
}

public void setIsScheduledForCompletion(Integer isScheduledForCompletion) {
    this.isScheduledForCompletion = isScheduledForCompletion;
}
```

}

[image: Image of error]

Comment: What is `ConnectionRequest` object?

Comment: @code_mechanic It's the name of the DB. I'm new to JPA queries. I assume I wrote this incorrectly?

Comment: Which class are you mapping to the connection_request table?

Comment: @MatheusCirillo 

Entity
Table(name = "connection_request")
public class ConnectionRequest

Comment: @CodeJ Does this object has this property `dateTimeRequestExpires` from error message?

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes it does. Could it be trying to find it in user? (where it is not)

Comment: datetimerquestexpires, check if you have that in your model, and next time don't use images

Comment: @nbk Yes it is there, and I used an image only for the error. Didn't think that would be an issue as it is allowed and many people ask for it that way

Comment: check also the tables if they have it, the error doesn't come from the query it self.

Comment: @nbk That's what is throwing me. It's only in connection_request DB. As a side note, if I add 'dateTimeRequestExpires' to the query it says the same thing for the next column in the connection_request DB

Comment: Edit the question and post your entire `ConnectionRequest` class. I think the problem is happening because of the native query. So, to be sure, I have to see the `ConnectionRequest` class. . .

Comment: @MatheusCirillo Done, and thank you

Comment: But why is the column there if it does not exist? That's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are mapping your native query to entity object, hibernate finds out that is an entity object due to all these annotation and everything, it is checking if this object is in <s>persistence context</s> cache or not.

So, it doesn't find it and creates one, but then it tries to map the resultset from your query to this entity object but at the time of mapping it doesn't find all the columns to initialise the entity (notice here column is expected but if value is null it may work).

But, if all columns are provided it is able to map to entity object.

Let me give you this example, suppose I have this `Car` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "car name`s must be not empty")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "production_year", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime productionYear;
    private boolean tested;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;
}
```

and my repository method is this

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, brand_id, production_year from car", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Car> findAllCars();
```

Notice that `tested` is not there, so hibernate issue same error

```
could not execute query [select id, name, brand_id, production_year from car]

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'tested' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
```

But if I include `tested`

```
 @Query(value = "select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Car> findAllCars();
```

Hibernate does this

```
      : Unable to locate native-sql query plan in cache; generating (select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car)
2021-04-09 00:54:02.143 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery     : Starting processing of sql query [select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car]
2021-04-09 00:54:02.198 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.c.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor      : Mapping alias [alias1] to entity-suffix [0_]
2021-04-09 00:54:02.206 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : SQL query: select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car
2021-04-09 00:54:02.223 DEBUG 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car
Hibernate: select id, name, brand_id, production_year, tested from car
2021-04-09 00:54:02.364 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering statemen
```

If you look further down, it will give something like this

```
 : Object not resolved in any cache: [com.example.stackoverflow.model.Brand#1]
2021-04-09 00:54:02.559 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Fetching entity: [com.example.stackoverflow.model.Brand#1]
2021-04-09 00:54:02.560 DEBUG 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select brand0_.id as id1_0_0_, brand0_.name as name2_0_0_, brand0_.production_year as producti3_0_0_ from brand brand0_ where brand0_.id=?
Hibernate: select brand0_.id as id1_0_0_, brand0_.name as name2_0_0_, brand0_.production_year as producti3_0_0_ from brand brand0_ where brand0_.id=?
2021-04-09 00:54:02.562 TRACE 40352 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering statement [HikariProxyPreparedStatement
```

And in this case it successfully converts.

#### Solution to your problem

So if you want to use entity to be returned, you would have to provide all fields, otherwise you can use interface projections or something this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893870/return-custom-object-from-spring-data-with-native-query) suggests

Comment: That explained it perfectly! Thank you so very much!

Comment: Generally for native query, I have always used custom DTO or interface projection (where fields are smaller), so you should try to avoid entity conversion from native query.