# converting entities to dtos in most efficient way in bulk queries inside Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

What is the most efficent way to retrieve **all** entites from a table , and then transfer them to List of Dtos .

Im working inside spring boot application and my database is of **elastic search** with the following starters :

```
>  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

One naive way would be to use **findAll()** method of my repository and than iterate manually one by one over each entity .

Is there a more efficient way of doing so ? maybe the repo can give the result directly in Dto format some how ? or any other technique ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I removed the spring-jpa tag because no relation to JPA was visible. If there is some relationship to JPA please clarify and use the spring-data-jpa tag or spring-orm if it is related to the Spring Framework itself.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424632/1654233

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient (use of JVM resources) way is to use the lowest level Java API available for your store and use whatever it returns as the basis to create your DTO instances using hand-coded Java code.

Tools like Spring Data aim at making your life as ad developer easier, but they have to use reflection and Co to create instances. While they do a lot of smart stuff to do that efficient hand coding it will be faster.